# I don't understand the detailed behavior of the threshold working in fcluster (method ='complete')

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Xi=[[0,5,10,8,3],[5,0,1,3,2],[10,1,0,5,1],[8,3,5,0,6],[3,2,1,6,0]]

Xi = Distance matrix

```
shc.fcluster(shc.linkage(Xi,'complete'),9,criterion='distance')
```

in this code threshold = 9

after clustering result is array([3, 1, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int32)

i don't understand why not array [2 ,1 ,1, 1, 1]

this image means after clustering
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17806FuPuNpJiqhT12jiuFOMGNUvB1vjT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram, fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

You have this distance matrix

```
Xi = np.array([[0,5,10,8,3],[5,0,1,3,2],[10,1,0,5,1],[8,3,5,0,6],[3,2,1,6,0]])
```

we can visualize as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Xi)
# fill NaNs and mask 0s
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
mask = np.zeros_like(df)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='.0f', cmap="YlGnBu", mask=mask);
```

[image]

Now, we get the pdist

```
p = pdist(Xi)
```

and the linkage

```
Z = linkage(p, method='complete')
```

You set `9` as threshold so

```
dendrogram(Z)
plt.axhline(9, color='k', ls='--');
```

[image]

you have 3 clusters

```
fcluster(Z, 9, criterion='distance')

array([3, 1, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
#      0  1  2  3  4   <- elements
```

and it's correct, you can verify with the dendrogram that

- elements `1`, `2` and `4` in cluster `1`
- element `3` in cluster `2`
- element `0` in cluster `3`

If you want two cluster only, you have to choose `12`, for example, as thershold

```
dendrogram(Z)
plt.axhline(12, color='k', ls='--');
```

[image]

and so you have your expected result

```
fcluster(Z, 12, criterion='distance')

array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
#      0  1  2  3  4   <- elements
```

Comment: Thanks! but Xi is already pdisted dataframe ㅠㅠ

Comment: Your `Xi` is a 5x5 distance matrix. `pdist` is an array made of the lower triangular nilpotent matrix, by column, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884461/how-can-i-extract-the-distances-between-points-within-a-dendogram-in-python/66887576#66887576